# Set solr search term required characters

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Where in Solr can we set the limit for required characters in Solr search terms?

For example, I want to set the search term characters limit to nothing which should return all the results

Another example-

Suppose, I want to set the search term characters limit to 5. So when I search for "apple" (5 characters) or "orange" (5 characters or more) should return results. In this case, if I search for "cat", it should not return any results as the minimum required characters is 5.

**Where do we set such required characters limit for search terms in Solr?**

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to index and / or search terms with a predefined interval of characters you can do that by configuring a LengthFilter in your analyzer (at index and / or query time depending on your specific needs)

See here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory

Comment: Hi Andrea. I am no expert at Solr. Could you please explain what you meant when you said "If you don't want to index and / or search terms with a predefined interval of characters"?

Comment: Eh, it's hard with so few lines. Basically: your field has a certain type which in this case must be a TextField. A TextField, in schema, has two analizer chains (index time or query time, in case only one analyzer is defined then is applied to both). Putting the LengthFilter in index analyzer means that fields that don't meet min & max length contraint won't be indexed; putting the filter in the query analyzer means that search terms that doesn't meet min/max constraints will be ignored. The effect is moreless the same...but if you don't want such terms don't index them.

Comment: Thanks Andrea! Btw, you can always Update your answer when you need extra lines

Comment: My question is more with just the search terms that user enter to search for something. Solr should be able to return results only when search term satisfies minimum length of character constraint. So, for this, from what you mentioned - "putting the filter in the query analyzer means that search terms that doesn't meet min/max constraints will be ignored" should satisfy? right? Note: I don't want to mess with indexing at all.

Comment: You will have the same results both at index and query time. The difference is that in index case tokens are not indexed (i.e. smaller index but length constraint are hard-coded) while in query case tokens are there but search terms they are filtered out at runtime. BTW if you think (not at the moment because I believe you should try before) the answer is correct please accept it.