# Getting SolrException : Boosting query defined twice for query

Tags: solr

I have created two query documents with names 'makeup', and 'make up' in elevate.xml.

When I execute the elevate solr query, I am getting exception "Boosting query defined twice for query".

whereas when I save two documents with names 'ChildCare', and 'Child Care', Solr is returning the results.

Below is my Solr query:

```
    http://localhost:8983/solr/oneweb-collection/elevate?
q=*:*&defType=edismax&fl=id&fl=title&fl=subtitle&fl=course_code&
fl=cricos_code&fl=course_introduction&fl=outcome&fl=page_url&
fl=score&fl=%5Btafe_elevated%5D&rows=3&wt=json
```

When I save the document nodes, system internally replacing the spaces and storing the documents with same name.

What is the resolution for this issue?

Config for elevator:

```
    <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
       <str name="queryFieldType">text_general</str>
       <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
       <str name="forceElevation">true</str>
       <str name="exclusive">true</str>
       <str name="editorialMarkerFieldName">test_elevated</str>
    </searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <int name="rows">3</int>
      <str name="fl">id,title,subtitle,course_code,cricos_code,course_introduction,outcome,page_url,[test_elevated],score</str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: May because the word “up” is too short it’s ignored resulting in similar search results.. what if the keyword length is decreased in settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/21147071/3254405

Comment: What is your actual elevation configuration when the request fails?

Comment: Hi Mats, Below is my elevation configuration.

<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
<str name="queryFieldType">text_general</str>
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
<str name="forceElevation">true</str>
<str name="exclusive">true</str>
<str name="editorialMarkerFieldName">test_elevated</str>
</searchComponent>

Comment: <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <str name="defType">edismax</str>
     <int name="rows">3</int>
     <str name="fl">id,title,subtitle,course_code,cricos_code,course_introduction,outcome,page_url,[test_elevated],score</str>
     <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>elevator</str>
  </arr>
 </requestHandler>

Comment: But what is in elevator.xml? Since it works when you change it - it's usually a good idea to start there.

Comment: elevate.xml to be precise :)

Comment: My elevate.xml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elevate>
   
   <query text="MS3">
      <doc id="18342"/>
   </query>
   <query text="MS4">
      <doc id="18342"/>
   </query>
   <query text="MS5">
      <doc id="18342"/>
   </query>
   <query text="MS1">
      <doc id="18342"/>
   </query>

   <query text="makeup">
      <doc id="17718"/>
   </query>

         <query text="make up">
      <doc id="17718"/>
   </query>

   <query text="huxley">
      <doc id="17718"/>
   </query>
</elevate>